# Retrieving first X words from a string in Oracle Select

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I need to select the first X words in a string, where x can be any number from 0-100.   Is there an easy way to do this?  I found the following example to select the first 2 words from a string:

```
select regexp_replace('Hello world this is a test', '(\w+ \w+).*$','\1') as first_two
from dual
```

How would I select the first X words from a string where X can be a number from 0-100?

Comment: In what form do you need the result? As a single string? Or one column per word? Or one row per word?

Comment: As a single string.  Rene's solution below worked except I have some strings that have two spaces in between and it is failing on those.  It was not his fault since I did not mention that.

Comment: @Robert Smith: I have updated my answer so that it works with two (or more) spaces between the words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selecting the first four words:

```
select
   regexp_replace(
     'Hello world this is a test etc',
     '(((\w+)\s){4}).*',  -- Change 4 to wanted number of words here!
     '\1'
   )
   from dual;
```

**Edit**

The above solution only works if the words are seperated by *exactly one* white space character. If the words are seperated by one or more white space characters, the `\s` must be extended to `\s+`:

```
select
   regexp_replace(
     'Hello    world   this   is a   test     etc',
     '(((\w+)\s+){4}).*',  -- Change 4 to wanted number of words here!
     '\1'
   )
   from dual;
```

Comment: If there are two spaces, what would be the change? I have a string such as 'Hello world  this is a test etc' that has two spaces and is failing.  Thanks.

Comment: Certainly, you could add a quantifier after the `\s`, like `{1,2}`.

Comment: It is working now, the "Edit" above works for strings with two or more spaces correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This method takes the result of extracting the number of words you want, then reduces multiple spaces to one:

```
select trim(regexp_replace(regexp_substr('Hello         world this is a test etc', '(([^ ]*)( |$)*){3}'), ' +', ' '))
from dual;
```

EDIT:  This is getting ugly, but wrapped a TRIM() around it to get rid of the trailing space (the one after the last word selected).

Comment: It is working but the only little detail is that it's leaving an extra space at the end of the string.

Comment: Ok I added a TRIM() call around it to remove the trailing space and updated my post.  P.S. Rene's solution needs that too.

Comment: By the way, use a proportional font and wrap the selected string in square brackets like this to make it easy to see the space: select '[' || my_string || ']' from ....

Answer (score 0):

this would do it, but it may be a bit inelegant, replace "2" with the number of words to find

```
select substr('this is a number of words',1,instr('this is a number of words',' ',1,2))
from dual
```

does assume words always end with a space